# Comparing a variable based on category in R

Tags: r, method-comparison

I have a data like this:

```
ds <- structure(list(return = c(-1.11777941176471, -0.883516129032258, 
      3.71416129032258, 0.028483870967742, -2.05184375, -0.26984375, 
      5.07122058823529, 15.54915625, 0.557730769230769, 3.40277358490566
      ), factor_5 = c(0L, 1L,  1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
      .Names = c("return", "factor_5"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

These are nothing but stock returns and their classification. Now I need to test which returns are better - the returns of stock belonging to category 1 or 0. The mean, skewness and all other simple statistics are more or less the same and the density plots are also almost same. But now I need to say which category yields better returns. Is there any other test that I can carry out to do this?

Comment: How much data? How much is it skewed?

Comment: In all I have about 3000 observations per category. And when I checked the density plots of my return for different they are almost normal (maximum skewness is 1.6812 and min skewness is -0.3592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute sharpe ratio for stock returns, which is annualized return/annualized volatility i.e. does the investment return justify the risk

Below computation is just an illustration:

```
> ds.stat<-ddply(ds,.(factor_5),summarize,mean_return=mean(return),sd_return=sd(return))
> ds.stat$sharpe<-ds.stat$mean/ds.stat$sd
> ds.stat
  factor_5 mean_return sd_return     sharpe
1        0    0.163873  2.074606 0.07898993
2        1    4.636236  6.608111 0.70159769
```

If you compute sharpe ratio for longer time series, you could pick the series with greater sharpe ratio as better investment.

You could also look at `PerformanceAnalytics` or `quantmod` packages which have many utilities for financial statistics

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) This answer has given me the financial approach of the problem.

Comment: I know essentially nothing about financial statistics, but surely the OP's data **aren't** time series?

Comment: Indeed that is the case here, OP has combined the two series for comparison and provided us an extract but their origin **is** a time series

Answer (score 4):

This is your run-of-the-mill [independent samples t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_.28unpaired.29_samples).

```
# Check average values.
> aggregate(ds, by=list(group=ds$factor_5), mean)

  group   return factor_5
1     0 0.163873        0
2     1 4.636236        1
```

Is this difference in means statistically significant?

```
# t test to see if difference is statistically significant.
> t.test(subset(ds, ds$factor_5==0)$return, subset(ds, ds$factor_5==1)$return)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  subset(ds, ds$factor_5 == 0)$return and subset(ds, ds$factor_5 == 1)$return
t = -1.4439, df = 4.781, p-value = 0.211
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -12.54563   3.60090
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 0.163873  4.636236
```

Result: average returns are higher when `factor_5` is at `1`, but there's a 21.1% chance that there's no real difference, and that this result is down to chance.

(apologies for possibly non-idiomatic code - R isn't my first language, so to speak).

**Edit - Two additional points:**

- With only 5 cases in each condition, your chances of finding a statistically significant difference were always going to be extremely slim.
- Looking at your data, it's pretty obvious that the only reason there's a difference in the mean scores is because there's one return of 15 in the `1` condition. This also means that the t test may not be appropriate, as your data isn't normally distributed, so you can run the same analysis as the following instead, yielding the same result.

`wilcox.test(subset(ds, ds$factor_5==0)$return, subset(ds, ds$factor_5==1)$return)`

Comment: Actually, I posted only few data points from my dataset. In all I have about 3000 observations per category. And when I checked the density plots of my return for different they are almost normal (maximum skewness is 1.6812 and min skewness is -0.3592)

Comment: Ok, in that case, it's just a t test, which is the bread and butter of comparing the means of two groups.